# @Schedule annotated method not invoked in GlassFish 2.1 & EJB 3 

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, schedule

In my Stateless bean, I have the following lines:

```
@Schedule(minute="*/2", hour="*")
public void doSomething() {}
```

I expect that this method would be called every 2 minutes but when I deploy it, nothing happens. Besides, if I put @Schedule in a bean and no client invokes any methods of this bean (the bean instance has not been created yet), will the container or anything call this method every 2 minutes?

This is the first time I have used @Schedule annotation, I'd be very grateful if someone could give me some advice on these matters.

Best regards,

James Tran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using NetBean 6.7.1 with Java EE 5 and GlassFish v2.1. After I installed NetBean 7.0.1 with Java EE 6 and GlassFish v3.1 and use it to deploy my application, the @Schedule annotation could finally work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) is the link on timer service from EE 6 docs.

Note the relevant part --

**Automatic timers are created by the EJB container when an enterprise bean that contains methods annotated with the @Schedule or @Schedules annotations is deployed.** An enterprise bean can have multiple automatic timeout methods, unlike a programmatic timer, which allows only one method annotated with the @Timeout annotation in the enterprise bean class.

You could try doing the automatic scheduling from ejb-jar.xml instead of using @Schedule if that makes any difference. From the looks of it, I can't see anything wrong with how you've set it up except maybe to try

```
@Schedule(minute="0/2", hour="*")
```

**EDIT** See @bkails' comment below. That's probably not going to buy you anything.

Comment: "For expression x/y, the attribute is constrained to every yth value within the set of allowable values beginning at time x. [...] The wildcard character (*) can be used in the x position, and is equivalent to 0."

Comment: Hmmm... I am using Java EE 5 with GlassFish v2.1 in my application but it seems to me that the @Schedule annotation is a feature of Java EE 6. Is this the cause of this problem?

Comment: @Kal -- "That'll do it" means Java EE 5 is not the cause of the problem? If so, I really have no idea why it does not work =(

Comment: No .. Sorry, I should have explained better. Yes .. Using Jave EE 5 instead of Java EE 6 is likely cause of your problem.